# Eigen: find a triangular matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm using the Eigen library in C++ and have a symmetric matrix `M` of size `n`, how can I find the triangular matrix `L` such that `M = Lt x L`?

Comment: I'd suggest going to [math.se] for that question and applying the algorithms with eigen.

Comment: Can [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html) be helpful?

Comment: Yes Bob, I found that yesterday right after I'd asked the question here. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's the Cholesky decomposition (LLT) you're after,
or the LDLT if the eigenvalues of your matrix could be zero.

See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html for an overview.